# PostgreSQL with ODBC: "there is no parameter $1"

Tags: postgresql, odbc, parameterized

I have a insert statement:

    `INSERT INTO billData (
      tmStart, tsDuration, eCallDir, ...
    ) VALUES (
      $1,  -- tmStart
      $2,  -- tsDuration
      $3,  -- eCallDir
      ...
    );`

I use `SQLPrepare` to compile it, bind parameters by `SQLBindParameter`, and execute it by `SQLExecute`.

After all of there steps, the error code `42P02` (there is no parameter $1) was returned.

BTW: I'm also using the almost same code for MS SQL Server and MySQL, and these two DB are working very well, so I believe my code is correct.

PS: the PostgreSQL is v9.1; the psqlODBC is v9.01.0100-1.

============================================================
UPDATE:

And the following error occured: `42601` (syntax error at or near ",") when I'm using '?' as the parameter placholder:

    `INSERT INTO billData (
      tmStart, tsDuration, eCallDir, ...
    ) VALUES (
      ?,  -- tmStart
      ?,  -- tsDuration
      ?,  -- eCallDir
      ...
    );`

============================================================
UPDATE:

According to the suggestion from j.w.r, It works after adding `UseServerSidePrepare=1` option to the ODBC connection string.

A lot of thanks :-)

Comment: Please include that piece of code so that we too can believe it is correct :)

Comment: It just too long to paste here, and the C++ code are exactly same with the mSQL and MySQL versions. the only difference between the PostgreSQL and the mSQL/MySQL versions is the INSERT SQL statement: the parameter placeholders are changed from '?' to '$1, $2, ...'.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try setting the ODBC setting `UseServerSidePrepare=1` if it isn't already set and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, It worked after adding `UseServerSidePrepare=1`, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

============================================================
UPDATE:

According to the suggestion from j.w.r, It works after adding `UseServerSidePrepare=1` option to the ODBC connection string.

A lot of thanks :-)

Note: the `ByteaAsLongVarBinary=1` option should also be added if you want to parameterize a bytea field with SQLBindParameter.

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure prepared statements works well with PostgreSQL ODBC I think something is wrong with this statement code. At first I would remove comments to make this INSERT as simple as possible. I have just tried multiline INSERT with comments and with colon at ends and it worked well. I converted a little my test Python code:

```
import odbc

db = odbc.odbc('odbcalias/user/password')
c = db.cursor()
r = c.execute("""INSERT INTO billData (
        tmStart, tsDuration, eCallDir, ...
    ) VALUES (
        ?,  -- tmStart
        ?,  -- tsDuration
        ?,  -- eCallDir
        ...
    );""", (tmStart, tsDuration, eCallDir, ))
print('records inserted: %s' % (r))
```

Can you try it with ActivePython 2.7 (it already has `odbc` module)?

If it will work then enable ODBC tracing and test this program. In odbc sql trace file should be entries like:

```
...
python.exe odbc 924-e8c ENTER SQLExecDirect 
        HSTMT               00A029A8
        UCHAR *             0x00B5A480 [      -3] "INSERT INTO test_table(txt) VALUES (?)\ 0"
        SDWORD                    -3

python.exe odbc 924-e8c EXIT  SQLExecDirect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               00A029A8
        UCHAR *             0x00B5A480 [      -3] "INSERT INTO test_table(txt) VALUES (?)\ 0"
        SDWORD                    -3

python.exe odbc 924-e8c ENTER SQLNumResultCols 
        HSTMT               00A029A8
        SWORD *             0x0021FAA0

python.exe odbc 924-e8c EXIT  SQLNumResultCols  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               00A029A8
        SWORD *             0x0021FAA0 (0)

python.exe odbc 924-e8c ENTER SQLRowCount 
        HSTMT               00A029A8
        SQLLEN *            0x0021FBDC

python.exe odbc 924-e8c EXIT  SQLRowCount  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               00A029A8
        SQLLEN *            0x0021FBDC (1)
```

Then make similar trace for your application and try to locate what is different.